# PunRPC method isn't able to instantiate the gameObject on all clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

For you who are already familiar with Photon2, I want to ask for help.

I'm trying to do a simple shooting function, and the only thing it needs to do is to instantiate the bullet gameObject. But for some reason, what happens is that, when calling the RPC function to execute the shot, each player executes his shot in isolation, without interfering in anything on the other's screen (that is, each player instantiates the object only in his client , the object being non-existent to the client of the other). If I instantiate the object via PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(), it executes correctly, but I heard that the ideal is to avoid using this function for many objects because it slows down the server, so I really wanted to be able to do it using the PunRPC modifier!

If it helps in anyway, here are some code snippets from the player controller and the bullet controller

Code relating to player:

```
 void Update()
    {
        if(!playerView.IsMine)
            return;
        PlayerMove();
        PlayerRotation();
        /*if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
            HealthUpdate(-10f);
        */
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
            //ShootBullet();
            playerView.RPC("NetworkShootBullet",RpcTarget.All);
        }


    }


    public void ShootBullet(){
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("myBullet",bulletSpawn.transform.position,bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
    }


    [PunRPC]
    public void NetworkShootBullet(){
        Instantiate(bulletSprite,bulletSpawn.transform.position,bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
    }
```

if you want some more info on player code, here's the full thing: https://pastebin.com/d231WEHp

if the above wasn't enough, here's the source for the Bullet gameObject script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
public class BulletController : MonoBehaviourPun
{

    public Rigidbody2D rigid;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public float bulletLifeTime;
    public float bulletTimeCount;
    public Vector2 bulletDirection;
    public Vector2 initialPos;

    public PhotonView bulletView;


    public void SetDirection(Vector2 bulletDirection,Vector2 initialPos){
        this.bulletDirection = bulletDirection;
        this.initialPos = initialPos;

    }
    void Start()
    {
        rigid = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        bulletView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        bulletSpeed = 100f;
        bulletLifeTime = 5f;
        moveBullet();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(bulletTimeCount > bulletLifeTime){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        bulletTimeCount += Time.deltaTime;            
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        //check if collided with a player prefab that isn't yours
        if(collision.gameObject.name.Equals("myPlayer")){
            PlayerController collidedPlayer = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
            if(!collidedPlayer.playerView.IsMine){
                collidedPlayer.HealthUpdate(-10f);
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveBullet(){

        rigid.AddForce(transform.up*bulletSpeed,ForceMode2D.Force);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this this is what you are looking for: [Photon Manual Instantiation](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation#manual_instantiation)

You need to link instantiated object to ViewID in network, cache it and raise/catch an event